# Import Error: No Module named ldap, issues with python-ldap module installation on mac os Serira, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, installation, ldap, importerror, python-ldap

Running a simple standalone python script on mac os Sierra. I am getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_exists.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ldap
ImportError: No module named ldap
```

I went and tried installing using pip the module, I get the following output:

```
$sudo -H pip install
Requirement already satisfied: python-ldap in /usr/local /bin/python_ldap-2.4.28-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from python-ldap)
```

I tried testing:

```
$ python -c "import ldap"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ldap
```

Please suggest whats the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: I am also having this issue...

Comment: @tkeeler I still haven't found a resolution. Please let me know if you find one.

Comment: @polygot - I ended up just running it in a docker container. Not a solution, but wanted to let you know what I ended up doing.